# HTML to PDF best way for javascript (JQuery/AngularJS)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, pdf

I have read a lot of stuff about making PDF from HTML and still don't really know how to do it. I used @media print, but I can't delete footer/header with generated date and link (localhost...). @page {margin: 0} can't work for multiple pages.
I've got a webpage where user can write something in input fields and save it. Then can print it with their information.

I have to search the best way for it, maybe something like jsPDF? But it's too bad for input forms i think.

Please help and sorry for my english writing style ;')

@edit need something good for all browsers and with styles like ive got in CSS code.

Comment: useful link for you: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKKNMK

Comment: Thanks, I will try with this thing now. I can additionaly say, that i have to do that for all basic browsers (IE, Mozilla, Chrome)

Comment: Ok it works, but now it's pure a4 + text. I want styles - how i can do it?